# AjaxControlToolkit configuration in web.config update from 3.5 to 4.1.51116.0

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I added the AjaxControlToolkit with the NuGet Manager Console.

Now I get the this error:

**Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.51116.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' uses 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'**

But if I change the Version to 4.0.0.0 as it is in my other project that works, it wont work and still gives me the same error.

this is the Toolkit part in my web.conifg:

```
<controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
</controls>
```

Would be nice if someone could explain it to me, what im doing wrong? :)

p.s I am new in .Net